# Proxy_pass из url

Tags: nginx

Как можно взять из URLa параметр и подставить его в proxy_pass(сделать запрос на этот url), Можно ли как то rewriteом вывести в переменную этот урл и подставить в proxy_pass или как то по другому сделать?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/q/298392/292034 // ну и вообще, так как вам нужен не **обратный** (reverse) proxy, а **прямой** (forward), то и ищете информацию соответствующим запросом: google://nginx+as+forward+proxy